# Minecraft Wither Boss help

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

My little brother and I are enjoying Minecraft on the Wii u and we heard about the wither, so we decided to make him. The only thing is we didn't do our homework on this. We summoned him out in the open not in the nether and we don't have any armor! We were able to damage him a bit but he is too high in the air, any tips or ideas?

Comment: Just noting, it might be a good idea to flee.  I don't know if he will despawn, but he should stop trying to kill you if you get far far away.

Comment: Isn't this the plot of the Telltale series?

Comment: Aziniaga if my answer is at any help for you, could you validate it ?

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to change the environment to make it easier to kill the Wither, so you will have to focus on equipment. If the Wither is too out of control, then you will have to abandon your base for now and start a new one before obtaining these items.

Essentials:

1. **Sword with Smite V** - Since the Wither is undead, this will give bonus damage.
2. **Bow** - If you hit him hard enough with a bow, he will drop down for you to use your sword. Enchant it with Power V, though Infinity can be good too.
3. **Armor** - Blast protection is good, but having a full Protection 4 is better (as you can have it for any fight). The Thorn Enchantment can be fun, but not worth that much.
4. **Potion** - Having potions like Strength, Heal, and Regeneration is good. If you don't have any, go for the golden Apple. It is much better then nothing.
5. **Milk** - Having a bucket of milk can be a really good idea because it gets rid of the poison inflicted by the Wither Boss. Bring a couple buckets in case you get hit a lot.

Having Diamond Sword and Armor is really needed if you go for him in Hard difficulties, though an Iron Sword might be enough if you're skilled.

Comment: If you donwvote, comment to explain why maybe.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Thanks for the Edit mate, i wrote that at Work and in a hurry :)

Comment: The OP asked how to deal with a Wither that is on the loose, not on how to prepare for a new fight.

Comment: @Thorsal If you know how to read you can see on the part with the bow that I explain it is going to drop donw if you hit it enought